# Entity Framework Core generated SQL in Application Insights dependency

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-application-insights

I have been moving several database calls into EF Core and we are not getting any of the queries showing up in the "data" of the dependencies captured by Application Insights. This would be ideal if the parameters are not captured, so we could aggregate on the query inside "exec sp_executesql". We have been getting the queries for non EF DB access. Is this just not implemented for EF Core yet?

Comment: Could you pls clarify (1)are you running your application on 4.5.2 or 4.6 framework? (2) did you instrument by just installing the SDK or you also enabled profiler using status monitor or webapp extension?

Comment: @AlexBulankou (1)The project is targeting 4.6.1. (2)I have both the Status Monitor on the machine and Application Insights libraries 2.0.0 (Jumping to 2.0.1 fails, looks like it was only intended for a mobile hotfix so we stayed with 2.0.0). It is capturing stored procedure names and queries from the ADO classes, but nothing with EF Core (RC1).

Comment: AI has a list of methods that it instruments: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/master/Src/DependencyCollector/Shared/Implementation/ProfilerRuntimeInstrumentation.cs#L70 If EF call eventually gets though one of this methods it would be tracked. Can you give a sample of your EF usage?..

Comment: There is an issue reported regarding the support for logging parameters.
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/193